# Self study problem: Predicting performance using multivariate linear regression

Tags: r, regression, multivariate-regression

I'm trying to improve my statistics knowledge using football(soccer) results. So, this is a self study problem. You don't have to provide a complete solution. Pointing me in the right direction is sufficient as well.

I have a book where the author tries to show how a current season home edge can be estimated using information from earlier seasons. He writes "In order to incorporate both aspects we have treated the home edge of the last 10 years as a regression problem." And continues by presenting this formula:

$$
HE_{est} = c_1HE_{last3} + c_2HE_{current}
$$

$HE_{current}$ is the current season home edge which is updated using information from the last three seasons ($HE_{last3}$) to arrive at a home edge estimate $HE_{est}$.

He then presents the following table where $N$ is the number of match days:

```
N | 0 | 6 | 11| 17| 22| 27| 33|
c1|.89|.80|.67|.62|.61|.53|.52|
c2| 0 |.11|.24|.29|.31|.40|.42|
```

Here's what I understand he is doing:
First of all, this is a multivariate linear regression problem with $c_1$ and $c_2$ being the coefficients. Since the formula is probably an attempt at predicting the season home edge from running season information, I assume that $HE_{est}$, the dependent variable, is actually the future home advantage. So, I figure, he calculated the home edge of each season of the last ten years and the home edge of the preceding seasons. Finally, he also calculated the home edge at each $N$ for each season (e.g. $HE$ at $N=6$, at $N=11$ and so on)  and estimated the coefficients $c_1$ and $c_2$ using the linear model above.

I tried to do this with R myself and I couldn't reproduce the numbers in the table above. My data looks like this:

```
data <- matrix(c(.15,.46,.46,.5,.02,.38,.21,.4,.43,.26,.43,.18,.57,.54,.16,.42,.20,.49,.47,.18,.43,.28,.47,.45,.14,.41,.19,.51,.46,.2,.4,.19,.53,.48,.2,.51,.49,.34,.37,.4),5,8)

colnames(data) <-c("HE.6","HE.11","HE.17","HE.22","HE.27","HE.33","HE.curr","HE.last3")
```

This is only the information of 5 years. However, it's the same years he used for his data set, just the first five years are missing. So, the resulting coefficients should be good approximations of what he calculated. However, they are not. If I do e.g.:

```
lm(HE.curr ~ HE.last3 + HE.17,as.data.frame(data))
```

I get:

```
Coefficients:
(Intercept)         HE.17     HE.last3  
    0.09440      0.79265     -0.07591
```

This result is incorrect. `HE.17` is $HE_{current}$ at $N=17$. The coefficient $c_2$ should be 0.29 but according to this linear model it's 0.79. Since my results are wrong and he doesn't report any intercept (except maybe $c_1=0.89$ at $N=0$ which I'm not sure about), I get the impression, I'm using the wrong model here. What am I missing?

Comment: You have to explicitly remove the intercept from the model, if you don't want to have it. This can be achieved by appending $-1$ to the formula, i.e. `E.curr ~ Y.17 + HE.last3 -1`

Comment: Well, that solves the problem with the intercept but the coefficients are still wrong. The missing intercept also was just one reason why I think I'm using the wrong model. Apart from that, my results are just plain wrong.